# Why does the value not change handler not work?

Tags: reactjs

I have an output, usernameChangeHandler....It is meant to change the person state when a user is inputted into the input field. I had passed the e value down to change the state, but it is not updating it. I have succesfully logged its value, but it does not change the state..Could someone please help?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    username: 'supermax',
    persons: [
      {name: 'Max', age: 28},
      {name: 'Tom', age: 28},
      {name: 'Jeff', age: 28}
    ],
    showPerson: false
  }

  
  usernameChangedHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({persons: [
      {name: e.target.value, age: 28},
      {name: 'Tom', age: 28},
      {name: 'Jeff', age: 28}

    ]})

    console.log(e.target.value)

  }

   showPersons = () => {

    const doesShow = this.state.showPerson
    this.setState({showPerson: !doesShow})
    
    
    console.log(this.state.showPerson);
    console.log('button clicked');
  }


  render(){

    let persons = null 

    if (this.state.showPerson) {
      persons = (
        <div>

          <UserInput changed={this.usernameChangedHandler}/>

          {this.state.persons.map(person => {

           return <UserOutput 

            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            />

          })}

        </div>

      )
    }


    console.log(this.state.showPerson);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.showPersons}>Switch Names</button>
        
        {persons}
        

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

User input.js

import React from 'react'

```
const userInput = (props) => {
        const style = {
            border: '2px solid red'
        }

        return (
            <input
             type='text'
             style={style}
             onChange={props.changed}
             value={props.currentname}
             />
        )
}


export default userInput
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React re-uses event objects (because it has an [internal synthetic event system](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)). Due to that, referencing `e.target.value` directly can be problematic when it's part of an asynchronous function call, which `this.setState()` just so happens to be. Remember that the `this.setState()` updater function does *not* execute synchronously when the event handler is triggered - instead it happens later, when React flushes the state update queue. By that time, `e.target.value` no longer has a defined value. However, if you call `console.log(e.target.value)` inside of the event handler, that statement *does* execute synchronously, leading one to believe that `e.target.value` has a persistent value when in fact it does not.

The fix is simple: assign `e.target.value` to a variable inside of the scope of your event handler. That way, even if `e.target.value` changes or becomes undefined, the variable you have declared will retain its value and can be used inside of `this.setState()`.

```
  usernameChangedHandler = (e) => {
    // note this is declared _outside_ of the setState updater function
    const newValue = e.target.value;

    this.setState({persons: [
      {name: newValue, age: 28},
      {name: 'Tom', age: 28},
      {name: 'Jeff', age: 28}
    ]});

    console.log(newValue);
  };
```

Comment: This is fantastic and thanks for the in-depth.